# Unable to install visvis using pip in python

Tags: python, installation, pip, permission-denied

I successfully added pip to python on my ubuntu. However when I try to install visvis using pip:

```
pip install visvis
```

I get the following error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visvis': Permission denied
```

How do I solve this? Btw, I am downloading visvis to easily plot hundreds of spheres. Any suggestions on what else I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command as superuser to install the package system-wide.

For example, use `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install visvis
```

Answer (score 2):

Better if you use virtualenv for your packages: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/